# Excluding folders in Winrar

Tags: winrar

**A Day with Winrar**

All I wanted to do was exclude folders and their contents using wildcards, and even after reading the docs, it turned into a guessing game...

So my test bed looks like:

```
C:\!tmp1\f1
C:\!tmp1\f1\f1.txt
C:\!tmp1\f1\a
C:\!tmp1\f1\a\a.txt
C:\!tmp1\f2
C:\!tmp1\f2\f2.txt
C:\!tmp1\f2\a
C:\!tmp1\f2\a\a.txt
```

And I am executing:

```
C:\>"c:\program files\winrar\winrar.exe" a -r !tmp1.rar !tmp1
```

which gives me a rar with !tmp1 as the root (sole top level folder).

The exclude switch is `-x<filepathpattern>` and may be included multiple times.

So, given that we want to exclude f2, and all its subcontents...

```
-x*\f2\*
```

removes the contents, but leaves f2

```
-xf2
```

does nothing - includes all

```
-x\f2
```

does nothing - includes all

```
-x*\f2
```

does nothing - includes all (now I'm mad), so surely it must be..

```
-x\f2\
```

nope, does nothing - includes all. So it has GOT to be...

```
-x*\f2\
```

hell no, does nothing - includes all. and I already know that

```
-x*\f2\*
```

removes the contents, but leaves f2. Onward we go...

```
-x*f2\
```

does nothing - includes all. Grrrr. Aha! how about...

```
-x!tmp1\f2\
```

nope, does nothing - includes all. WTF. Alright, So it has GOT to be...

```
-x!tmp1\f2
```

Holy moly, it worked! Hmmm, then how come....

```
-x*\f2
```

does not work? ***This was the little demon that sent me down this crazed path to begin with and should have worked!***

Given all that, do I dare try to go after `*/a/*` directories, removing contents and the dirs?

```
-x*\a
```

does not work, of course, does nothing.

```
-x*\*\a
```

does not work, of course, does nothing.

```
-x!tmp1\*\a
```

nope. But...

```
-x*\a\*
```

removes contents of both dirs, but leaves the folders. So, in desperation I can use the `-ed` switch which will not store empty folders, but this is a broad hack, I want to eliminate the folders specified not all empty folders.

With my animosity growing toward winrar, I am passing the baton of information forward with an eye to that glorious day when we will know how to specifically exclude a folder and its contents using wildcards and not using the `-ed` switch.

Comment: Consider the possibility that if you exclude a directory and include files in it, it gets created anyway.  The documentation says you can include the -x directive multiple times.  Did you try `-x!tmp1\*\a\* -x!tmp1\*\a`?

Comment: No, I didn't try that based on the try of `-x!tmp1\f2` worked at pruning that whole limb, so why shouldn't `-x!tmp1\*\a` work the same? I will try it though, thanks for your input.

Comment: @MarkRobbins, could you ever solve this issue? Could you try my solution?

Answer (score 16):

(Quite old question but still may be relevant)

Maybe what you simply needed was this :

`-x*\f2 -x*\f2\*`

two exclude switches, should remove directory f2 and all its contents.

Answer (score 9):

An even older question by now, but came across this question so I reproduced your folder structure and, at least nowadays (Winrar 5.11, not the latest but quite new), this works:

```
-x*\f2
```

So the whole command line is:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -m5 -s !tmp1.rar !tmp1 -x*\f2
```

And this is what is stored in the .rar file:

```
!tmp1\f1\a\a.txt
!tmp1\f1\f1.txt
!tmp1\f1\a
!tmp1\f1
!tmp1
```

Similarly, if you use `-x*\a`, all `a` folders are excluded, storing this:

```
!tmp1\f1\f1.txt
!tmp1\f2\f2.txt
!tmp1\f1
!tmp1\f2
!tmp1
```

Finally, combining both parameters (`-x*\f2 -x*\a`), you get this:

```
!tmp1\f1\f1.txt
!tmp1\f1
!tmp1
```

Answer (score 2):

To manage large list of files to be excluded, you can create text fie and write all excluded files/folders relative to the source folder:

1) create file list.txt, write the name of excluded files/folders
note: * refer to the source, all files/folders are  relative to the source folder

*\f2
*\f3

2) Run the command

```
       rar a -r  -x@list.txt target.rar source-folder
```